# Navigate to Class with namespace

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

PhpStorm have support for CamelCase in `Navigate > Class ...`. If I search for a class name `HttpResponse` for example, I can type `HRes` to find the class in the search bar.

But I can't find a way to search with namespace by this way. CamelCase seems to work only on the class name.

I have a project with a lot class with the same name in different namespace and I need to search the class in the list and since PhpStorm change the order depending on context, It's clearly take few seconds to find the good one.

I've the same result with `Navigate > Class ...` and new magic shortcut `2 x Shift`

Is there is any tips that allow to search by namespace ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Sure, just separate namespace part from class name using `\` character.**

---

Lets assume we have 2 similarly named classes in different namespaces (just an example):

```
App\Controller\Search
App\Model\Search
```

To see only 1st entry -- you will have to type `c\se`; to see only 2nd -- `m\se`.

---

Other than that -- there is a ticket for a class navigation using CamelCase only.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-19488 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne, you save my day :) too dumb i'm am too not have found it myself :)